# Algorithm to find the intersection of two or more songs

Tags: c, algorithm

Lets say we have a bunch of radios and each radio plays the same song on a loop over and over again.
Is it possible to synchronize all the songs from all the radios? Can we find a time where we hear all the songs from the beginning?

For the sake of simplicity we will say that we only have two radios.

I have the following formulas :

c and z represent the length of the song in seconds.
a and x represent the current position in the song ( in seconds )
S represents the time when C and Z synchronize. ( When both songs start at the same time )

For example :

```
Song 1
a = 17 : the time before the song ends.
b = 8 : the rest of the song.
c = a + b which is the full song in seconds.
And
Song 2 
x = 8 : the time before the song ends.
y = 9 : the rest of the song.
z = 8 + 9 which is the full song in seconds.

Song 1 : a + ( a + b) => S
Song 2 : x +(( x + y ) × n) => S

Song 1 : 17 + ( 17 + 8) => 42
Song 2 : 8 + ((8 + 9)) = 25
So in order to synchronize song 2 with song 1 we have to multiply (x + y)    
by two and add x to it.

Song 2 : 8 + ((8 + 9) x 2) => 42

So S = 42 and so the two songs will synchronize after 42 seconds.
```

Now This first example is the simplest one. For the other cases i would have to multiply z and c by more than two in order to get the appropriate S for them.

I have some other inputs , and i've tried to come up with an algorithm that will return S for me , but i had no luck with that.

Here is what i came up with so far :

```
c = a + b
a = 16
b = 4
c = 20
s = 216
```

And

```
z = x + y
x = 12
y = 5
z = 17
s = 216
S is the LCM of c and z
```

In the first example S was found this way :

```
s = x +(z × n)
n = ( s − x ) ÷ b
12 + ( 17 × 12) = 216
```

and

```
s = a + (c × n)
n = ( s − a ) ÷ b
16 + ( 20 × 10 ) = 216
```

I came up with the two formulas below Based on the value of S. But i need to figure out a way to find n without actually using S.
Or in other words i need to figure out a way to find how many times i should multiply ( a + b) by n and ( x + y) by n to get S.

```
n = ( s − a ) ÷ b
S = x + ( y × n)
```

But These formulas obviously won't work as they require S. And we can't use that because that should be the result of the formula that i am trying to come up with.

Here are other examples for some calculations :

```
a2 = 52
b2 = 4
c2 = 56
s2 = 276

x2 = 60
y2 = 12
z2 = 72
s2 = 276
```

Here is a situation where it will never be Synchronized :

```
A1 = 14
B1 = 4
C1 = 18
S1 = Never synchronizes

A2 = 19
B2 = 5
C2 = 24
S2 = Never synchronizes
```

And Here are some situation where the songs are already Synchronized :

Case 1

```
A2 = 17  
B2 = 0 
C2 = 17 
S4 = 0

A3 = 25  
B3 = 0 
C4 = 25  
S4 = 0
```

Case 2

```
A4 = 0 
B4 =  13  
C4 = 13  
S4 = 0


A5 = 0 
B5 = 21 
C5 = 21  
S5 = 0
```

I was thinking about using the Least Common Multiple but i am not sure how to implement it in this situation or if its the right solution for this problem.

The Algorithm i want to come up with should also work if there are more than 2 songs.
For example finding S for  3 or 4 songs.

The main problem with this Algorithm is deciding wether the two songs Synchronize or not , The calculation itself is not that hard.
Can you help me please ? Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure is it possible for any (a,b c) and (x,y,z)?

Comment: @MayurK: Good point. It's possible, regardless of the current offsets, whenever the song-lengths are pairwise coprime (that is, whenever no two song-lengths have a common factor). But when they're *not* pairwise coprime, the current offsets have to be right. For example, if two song lengths are both divisible by 7 seconds, then the difference between their current offsets will also have to be divisible by 7 seconds.

Comment: @ruakh, Yeah! i was solving with some random values and couldn't find S! Ok. Final equation I got is "(n1*c)-(n2*z)=(x-a)". We need to find integer n1 and n2 which satisfies this equation.

Comment: @MayurK No , its not possible for any (a,b,c) and (x,y,z). Please take a look at the OP i have added a few other cases.

Comment: @SpeedGoat, Yes. Did you check my previous comment? Finding n1 and n2 in "(n1*c)-(n2*z)=(x-a)" should solve the problem if number of stations is two right?

Comment: @ruakh There are some special cases where the songs are already synchronized ( if a or b = 0 ) or a case where they never synchronize. I added those to the OP, please check them out

Comment: @SpeedGoat: You mentioned that A=16 can never become synchronous. But it can be synchronous for n1=21 and n2=18, i.e. S=793. As ruakh pointed, it can be synchronous if C and Z are pairwise coprime.

Comment: @MayurK they don't Synchronize. S1 = 16 + (16 + 21) x 22 = 830
S2 = 19 + (19 + 24 ) x 19 = 836
S1 is different than S2 , they have to be equal in order for them to synchronize.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127962/discussion-between-mayurk-and-speedgoat).

Comment: @SpeedGoat Why are you calculating s as "s=a+(a+b)*n"? Are you stopping song at position "a" and restarting it? Or should it be played out completely and restarted? If it has to be restarted after playing out s should be "s=b+(a+b)*n".

Comment: Correct. S is the total time a song has to be played from the time you decide to synchronize the song right? So, you have to play "b" seconds first then for n repetition "(a+b)*n". So s=b+(a+b)*n?

Comment: No, S= a + (a+b)*n , A is actually the time before the song ends. And yes S is the total time a song has to be played

Comment: @SpeedGoat Then description you have given in first example is wrong.

Comment: @MayurK My bad. OP edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The least common multiple of `c` and `z` is the interval between consecutive times that the songs synchronize (if they synchronize at all). This means that, if we can determine one time, we can find the rest by adding (or subtracting) a multiple of the LCM. To find this time (and indeed, the LCM), use the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#B.C3.A9zout.27s_identity) to find integers `T, U` that satisfy the equation

```
 (c - a) + T*c = (z - x) + U*z
```

which is equivalent under the substitution `V = -U` to

```
 T*c + V*z = (c - a) - (z - x).
```

In detail, find the GCD of `c` and `z`, check that it divides `(c - a) - (z - x)`, then multiply the Bézout coefficients through by `((c - a) - (z - x))/GCD(c, z)`.

Comment: What if we had more than 2 songs to synchronize? lets say we had 3 or 4 songs

Comment: @SpeedGoat: Once you've done this calculation for a pair of songs, you can essentially view them as a "supersong" whose total length is LCM(length_1, length_2) and whose current position is total_length - time_until_synchronized. So you can synchronize the first two songs, then synchronize their "supersong" with the third, then synchronize the resulting "supersong" with the fourth, etc.

Comment: @David Eisenstat, What if ((c - a) - (z - x)) is not divisible by GCD(c,z)? Let me give you an example: (a,b,c)=(28,2,30) and (x,y,z)=(5,5,10). ((c - a) - (z - x))=-3 and GCD(c,z)=10. In this case ((c - a) - (z - x))  is not divisible by GCD. Also there are no integers T and V for which T*30+V*10=-3. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MayurK Nope, the songs never sync.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat
(a,b,c) = (50,40,104)
(z,y,z) = (60,12,132) 
((c - a) - (z - x)) = ((104-50) - (132-60)) = -18
GCD(c,z) = GCD(104,132) = 4
-18 is not divisible by 4 , so based on this we can conclude that it dosen’t sync.
But thats wrong , because they do sync at S=276

Another Case is this : 
(a,b,c) (12,4,36 )
(x,y,z) (12,5,29)
((c - a) - (z - x)) = ((36-16) - (29-12)) = 3
gcd(36,29) = 1
T = -4, U = 5 , V=-5
T*c + V*z = (c - a) - (z - x).
(-4*36)+(-5*29) = -289 which doses not equal ((36-16) - (29-12)) = 3
did i make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: @SpeedGoat Yes, what happened to the identity `a + b = c`?

Comment: @SpeedGoat: I am not sure if you have understood the GCD logic we are discussing correctly. (1) If GCD is 1, then you will always find a sync point. (2) If GCD >1, then you may or may not find sync point. It is nothing to do with divisibility. David Eisenstat, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I think this answer gives you basic idea about how you can approach the problem. You need to think and find the actual solution. I want to make two points. (1) Even I am not sure whether this logic is completely correct. David Eisenstat can explain it better. (2) Specifically in this example you dont need to calculate it because remaining times are same for both the songs (a=x). After 12s they will be in sync.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat After finding the GCD of c and z and checking it devides (c - a) - (z - x) and multiplying the coefficients by the result i got this :

(a,c) = 2 , 37 (x,z) (3,43) Correct =  S1 & S2 = 261
(a,c) = (52 56 ) ; (x,z) = (60 72) Correct = S1 & S2 = 276

(a,c) = (6 20) ;(x,z) = (12 17) 
Result :  S1 =136 , S2 = 97, T = 6 , U= 5
Correct:  T=10 U=12  s1[216] s2[216]

(a,c) = 17 25 
(x,z) =  8 17 
Result : S1 =67 , S2 = 59, T = 2 , U= 3
Correct: T= 1 U=2   s1[42]   s2[42]

I don't understand why in the first two cases it worked , but on the last two it didn't ,any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I have written this code with the logic i have mentioned in comments. Basic idea is to find integers n1 and n2 such that **(n1*c)-(n2*z)=(x-a)**

**Brief explanation about how I arrived at this equation:**

> s1 = a+(n1*c)
>
> s2 = x+(n2*z)
>
> We need s1=s2
>
> => a+(n1*c) = x+(n2*z)
>
> => (n1*c)-(n2*z) = (x-a)

We need to find n1 and n2 which satisfies the above equation. **The solution exists if and only if GCD of c and z divides (x-a)**.

Please note: This logic works for two stations.

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void findVal(unsigned int a, unsigned int c, unsigned int x, unsigned int z) ;
unsigned int getGCD(unsigned int n1, unsigned int n2);

int main()
{
    findVal(2, 37, 3, 43);
    return 0;
}

void findVal(unsigned int a, unsigned int c, unsigned int x, unsigned int z) {

    unsigned int  n1       = 0;
    unsigned int  n2       = 0;
    unsigned char foundVal = 1;
    unsigned int  s1       = a;
    unsigned int  s2       = x;

    //No need to find n1 and n2 if songs are already at the starting point.
    if((a == c) && (x == z))
    {
        s1 = 0;
        s2 = 0;
    }

    //No need to find n1 and n2 if remaining times are same.
    else if(a != x)
    {
       //Remaining times are not same.
       foundVal = 0;

       //Find GCD of c and z.
       unsigned int gcd = getGCD(c, z);

        //There is a solution only if the difference of x and a is divisible by the gcd.
       if(0 == (x-a) % gcd)
       {
           for(n2=1; n2<(unsigned int)-1; n2++)
           {
               unsigned int temp1 = (z*n2)+(x-a);
               if(0 == temp1%c)
               {
                    n1 = temp1/c;
                    s1 = a + n1*c;
                    s2 = x + n2*z;

                    foundVal = 1;
                    break;
               }
           }
       }
    }

    if(1 == foundVal)
    {
        printf("Found n1[%u] n2[%u] s1[%u] s2[%u]\n", n1, n2, s1, s2);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Could not find n1 and n2\n");
    }
}

unsigned int getGCD(unsigned int n1, unsigned int n2)
{
    while(n1!=n2)
    {
        if(n1 > n2)
            n1 -= n2;
        else
            n2 -= n1;
    }
    printf("GCD = %u\n",n1);

    return n1;
}
```

Output:

```
Found n1[21] n2[18] s1[793] s2[793]
```

Comment: findVal(17, 42, 8, 17) returns 59. Thats wrong , it should return 42 instead Like in the example in OP.
You just multiply multiply ( x + y) * 2 so we get "x + ((x + y) x 2) = 42 "

Comment: @SpeedGoat: How? Do you agree s1=a+n1*c and s2=x+n2*z are the equations to be solved for s1=s2? OR better you show your solution with s=42.

Comment: (a,b,c) = (17,8,25)
(x,y,z) = (8,9,17)
S1 = a + (a + b) = 17+ (17 + 8 ) = 42
S2 = x + ((x + y ) * n)  = 8 + ((8+9) * 2 ) = 42

Comment: @SpeedGoat You said c=42. Check your first comment.

Comment: @SpeedGoat: I found a generic solution for GCD=1 and GCD>1. I have updated the answer. Check your test vectors with this updated code.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a workaround for synchronising more than 2 songs but it will take a lot of time!

1. If the current positions of all the songs are `0`, then they are already synced.
2. If the remaining lengths of all the songs are `same`, then they will sync after that remaining length.
3. If these above tests (for trivial cases) fail, we use a heuristic approach:

We can use an object for each song with the following properties:

- current position, `x`
- remaining length, `y`
- total length, `z = x + y`
- played length, `p`

We create one such object for each song. The `x` and `y` values are input from the user, `z` is computed and `p` is initialised to `x`.

```
create a Min-Heap for the objects based on their `p` values.

for ( i = 1; i <= some_reasonable_value_like_10000; i++ )
{
    if (the `p` values of all objects are same)
        then break from the loop
    else
        increase the `p` value of the root of Min-Heap by `z` value of the corresponding object (and heapify, if required)
}
if ( i <= some_reasonable_value_like_10000)
    return `p` value of any object!
```

This algorithm will take exponential time in most cases, but, is useful if there are many songs. Also, it does not depend on the primality or divisibility of the parameters.

Reviews and suggestions on the algorithm are most welcome!

Comment: How do you decide whether synchronization is possible at all? I didn't get that part.

Comment: Well, I forgot that! Editing now.

Comment: I feel p should be initialized to y instead of x. You should playout the current song completely before restarting. Right? It is not clear in the question.

Comment: `p` is the played length, so it must be initialised with `x`.

Comment: We are adding z multiple times to p because we are playing that song multiple times in future. Is my understanding correct? If yes, p is REMAINING TIME for which song is played (including repetition). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: `p` in each iteration is the length of each song already played. It tells  something that has already performed, and cannot represent the remaining time for each song to get them all synced. If I could do this, then the problem would be solved easily.

Comment: The descriptions were misleading in the question. SpeedGoat has modified it and now it is clear to me. Please read the first example in the question and verify once whether your understanding is correct. :)