# Messages synchronization algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm

We have two infinitely repeating messages consisting of characters a-z. Each character takes a different amount of time units to transmit; a=1, b=2, c=4, d=8,e=16 ..., character | tells us current position in the message. Our job is to say how many units of time it will take to synchronize the two messages. Synchronization means that both messages begin at the same time.

Example:

We have message 1: ea|babab

and message 2: d|abaca

therefor we know that message 1 is bababea and message 2 is: abacad.

The messages will be synchronized in 42 units of time:

ea|bababea|          = 42

d|abacad|abacad|    = 42

Example 2:
message1: |acabbaaa message 2: |dcbabaaaa.

Solution: 0, because they are already synchronized.

We want to come up with an algorithm which will calculate the time until first synchronization occurs.

I am writing this in C. I have basically everything done, except for the algorithm itself.

I think this could maybe be done using extended Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: If I understand your problem statement correctly, the solution is a direct application of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered a different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564750/algorithm-to-find-the-intersection-of-two-or-more-songs/40565929#40565929) and I think solution to this problem is exactly the same. You need to solve the equation **m1Offset+(m1Len * intN1) = m2Offset+(m2Len * intN2)**

```
(m1Len * intN1) - (m2Len * intN2) = (m2Offset - m1Offset)
```

We need to find intN1 and intN2 which satisfies the above equation. **There will be a solution if and only if GCD of m1Len and m2Len divides (m2Offset - m1Offset)**.

In the code below,

- m1Len and m2Len: Length of messages m1 and m2 respectively. Ex: for "ea|babab" length is length of "bababea"=25 and in message "d|abaca", length of "abacad"=17
- m1Offset and m2Offset: Initial offsets. Ex: In message "ea|babab", "ea" is offset, which is equal to 17. Similarly in "d|abaca", "d" is offset, which is equal to 8.
- m1Time and m2Time should be equal and that is the first sync time.

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void findVal(unsigned int m1Offset, unsigned int m1Len, unsigned int m2Offset, unsigned int m2Len) ;
unsigned int getGCD(unsigned int n1, unsigned int n2);

int main()
{
    findVal(17, 25, 8, 17);
    return 0;
}

void findVal(unsigned int m1Offset, unsigned int m1Len, unsigned int m2Offset, unsigned int m2Len) {

    unsigned int  n1       = 0;
    unsigned int  n2       = 0;
    unsigned char foundVal = 1;
    unsigned int  m1Time   = m1Offset;
    unsigned int  m2Time   = m2Offset;

    //No need to find n1 and n2 if msgs are starting from beginning.
    if(((m1Offset == m1Len) && (m2Offset == m2Len)) || ((0 == m1Offset) && (0 == m2Offset)))
    {
        m1Time = 0;
        m2Time = 0;
    }

    //No need to find n1 and n2 if offset times are same.
    else if(m1Offset != m2Offset)
    {
       //Offset times are not same.
       foundVal = 0;

       //Find GCD of m1Len and m2Len.
       unsigned int gcd = getGCD(m1Len, m2Len);

       //There is a solution only if the difference of offsets is divisible by gcd.
       if(0 == (m2Offset-m1Offset) % gcd)
       {
           for(n2=1; n2<(unsigned int)-1; n2++)
           {
               unsigned int temp1 = (m2Len*n2)+(m2Offset-m1Offset);
               if(0 == temp1 % m1Len)
               {
                    n1 = temp1/m1Len;
                    m1Time = m1Offset + n1*m1Len;
                    m2Time = m2Offset + n2*m2Len;

                    foundVal = 1;
                    break;
               }
           }
       }
    }

    if(1 == foundVal)
    {
        printf("Found n1[%u] n2[%u] m1Time[%u] m2Time[%u]\n", n1, n2, m1Time, m2Time);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Could not find n1, n2, m1Time, m2Time\n");
    }
}

unsigned int getGCD(unsigned int n1, unsigned int n2)
{
    while(n1!=n2)
    {
        if(n1 > n2)
            n1 -= n2;
        else
            n2 -= n1;
    }
    printf("GCD = %u\n",n1);

    return n1;
}
```

Output:

```
Found n1[1] n2[2] m1Time[42] m2Time[42]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Though I found that following input creates infinite loop: findVal(16, 20, 19, 24)

Comment: @Mykybo: it is not infinite loop, it checks from 0 to UNSIGNED_INT_MAX and It takes time. You refer to my answer on that question. You may not find solution if message lengths are not pairwise co-prime, i.e. GCD(m1Len, m2Len) is >1.

Comment: Actually, findVal(52, 56, 60, 72): m1Len is 56 and m2Len is 72, which has GCD 8 (which is >1) and you can find solution: 276.

Comment: Yeah. if GCD>1, finding sync time is not guaranteed.

Comment: Is there no definite way to say if the solution exists? Running all the way to UNSIGNED_INT_MAX takes to much time.

Comment: @Mykybo I don't know. Even I am thinking about it. I will post if I find an answer.

Comment: @Mykybo: I have found a generic solution for GCD=1 and GCD>1. I have updated my answer. Test your test vectors with the updated code once.

Comment: s/UNSIGNED_INT_MAX/`UINT_MAX`/ This is C, not guess. Guess is not completely compatible with C; dragons be lurking...

Comment: @Seb Haha! What I meant is maximum unsigned value on that machine. I believe "(unsingen int) -1" should be the largest unsigned integer possible on any machine. Is my understanding right?

Comment: No. The largest unsigned integer would be `UINTMAX_MAX` (`(uintmax_t) -1`). For the largest `unsigned int`, you might find value in using the macro `UINT_MAX` as opposed to `(unsigned int) -1` (e.g. the former is succinct and idiomatic, and the latter is not so)... or you might not. Different boats float different folks.